# Magento migration from live to wamp server

Tags: magento-1.9, wampserver

SO for development purpose I moved my live magento site to my local dev environment so that I can setup Angular Js in it. steps I followed are as follows:

1. Migrated whole Db to local mysql server and also copied files in
   www folder of wamp
2. chnaged db information in local.xml
3. copied download.php file of magento 1.9 to the root folder and
       followed the process till download step but soon after that when I
       click continue it gives me following error even when i tried to run
       index.php it gives same error as "varien_autoload.php not found".
4. I tried checking permission as well but its in the same state

[please see the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHJBT.png)

Comment: Did you setup a Virtual Host for this site? Always best with a CMS/FRAMEWORK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: unrelated question

Comment: That was supposed to show you how to setup a Virtual Host. If you do that then the folder structure will match that on your LIVE site and things will start to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps:

Step 1: Backup the Magento MySQL Database.

Step 2: Transfer all Magento Files.

Step 3: Adjust the Magento Configuration (Db,User,Password) in the `app/etc/local.xml` file.

Step 4: Restore the Magento Database : Once you have adjusted the options above you should restore the database at the new location.

Step 5: You need to edit `core_config_data` and the values you need to change are in the path column. Change the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to match the new domain name by altering the value column for both records.